# Java - Find all the possible Subnets that a specific IP can be in the IPs range

Tags: java, oracle, ip, subnet

I'm trying to find a solution to the following:

I need somehow to get all matching Subnets that a specific IP can be in their IPs Range. 
For example, the IP 10.25.100.83:
It is in range of IPs of subnet 10.25.100.0/24 
It is also in range of subnet 10.25.100.0/25 IPs, and 10.25.100.64/26 .... etc

The reason I need to do this, is because I have a massive Oracle Table that contains only information of Subnet activations and de-activations (e.g. Subnet=10.25.100.0/24 Activation=10/04/2017 etc) and I need to find if a given specific IP was activated during a period.

If I process all the table results and then parse all subnets row-by-row and for each subnet search if the IP is in subnet's range, the result will take ages (if it will ever make it to finish).

So, I thought that it would be much easier and faster to find all the possible subnets that this IP can be in their range and search in Oracle with Subnet values.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you just sweep the mask from 0 to 32?

Comment: Convert the dotted-quad IP to `int` form.  The subnets it matches have the same high-order bits, with all remaining bits zero.  You can pretty easily build the matching subnets from the IP with a modest amount of bitwise arithmetic.